# Using threads for console application?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I don't know if I should use threads in console application.
When I choose choice 1 for START CLIENT, it starts client and recieves messages from server...

this is method called connectClient from switch case 1 :

```
void App::connectClient(){

if (this->client == NULL){
        this->client = new Client(QUrl(QStringLiteral("ws://localhost:10000")), 0);
        connect(this->client, SIGNAL(messageHasCome()), this, SLOT(listenToMessage()));

                qWarning() << "CLIENT IS CONNECTING TO PORT: 10000";                
}

else {
                qWarning() << "CAREFULL, CLIENT IS ALREADY CONNECTED AT PORT: 10000"; 
                emit signalShowMenu();          
}
```

}

PROBLEM is that even when SIGNAL SLOT is connected, when message is sent from server, it will not go to listenToMessage(), just once in the beggining.
So I was thinking if it happened only once, it might not be able to reach signal from server because it doesnt have its own thread? when I did that in GUi app it worked and every time there was message from server it displayed to textEdit.

**This is my application:**

> I have menu for console application:

**consoleApp.cpp**

```
m_out << "\n************MENU*****************\n";   
m_out << "(1): START CLIENT\n";
m_out << "(2): SHOW MESSAGE FROM CLIENT\n";
m_out << "(3): SEND MESSAGE\n";
m_out << "(4): EXIT\n";
m_out << "************************************\n";  
m_out.flush();
m_in >> m_choice;
```

My switch decides what to do:

```
switch (m_choice)
{
case 1:
    m_App->connectClient(); 
    break;

case 2:
    m_out << m_App->getMessageFromServer();
    m_out.flush();  
    showMenu();
    break;

case 3:
    sendMessagetoServerOptionChoosen();
    showMenu();
    break;

case 4: 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    break;  

default:
//  showMenu();
    break;
}
```

So What I would like to do is: whenever message from server is availible(signal messageHasCome()), than it would emit the signal listenToMessage() even when I am inside my menu... Should I use threads? I am confused, could you explain me how that works?

Thank you

**EDIT1**

Now I am trying following, i added this to class where is my menu:

```
class App_console : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread appThread;
```

into the menu I added this:

```
switch (m_choice)
    {
    case 1:
        //want to start a new thread here.  
        m_App->moveToThread(&appThread);//
        appThread.start(); //

        m_App->connectClient(); 

        break;
```

What I am missing... ? I want to add to different thread the object m_App or just the method m_App->connectClient();    how could I do that?

Comment: If you are actively waiting for user input and blocking the main thread for this then yes. you need another thread to do the work.

Comment: @Hayt ok I am reading about threads in Qt5.7 right now, do you have any suggestio? should I create threads wherever I am using signal slot system?

Comment: Try to read the Qt documentation and have a look at the examples. This usually helps to get started.  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html

Answer (score 0):

I sloved my problem:

**consoleApp.cpp**

To the constructor I added this, so I moved object m_App to the thread appThread, then I connected signals and slots and it works...
signal is from consoleApp and slot from m_App so this means when I call signal from consoleApp, it would start proces from m_App object

```
/****************************THREAD STUFF*****************/ 
m_App->moveToThread(&appThread);
connect(who,signal,who, slot);  
appThred.start(); 
/*******************************************************/
```